# hidden fields array structure

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadHiddenCheckBoxes() {
    var hdncheckbox = document.getElementById('hdnWeekDays')
    var checkbox0 = document.getElementById('sunday')
    hdncheckbox[0] = checkbox0.checked;
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('monday')
    hdncheckbox[1] = checkbox1.checked;
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('tuesday')
    hdncheckbox[2] = checkbox2.checked;
    var checkbox3 = document.getElementById('wednesday')
    hdncheckbox[3] = checkbox3.checked;
    var checkbox4 = document.getElementById('thursday')
    hdncheckbox[4] = checkbox4.checked;
    var checkbox5 = document.getElementById('friday')
    hdncheckbox[5] = checkbox5.checked;
    var checkbox6 = document.getElementById('saturday')
    hdncheckbox[6] = checkbox6.checked;
}
```

this is my JS

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.weekDays, new { id = "hdnWeekDays" })
        <input type="checkbox" id="sunday" style="float: left;" onchange="LoadHiddenCheckBoxes()" />
```

I also have a hiddenfor to bind data in model. weekDays is defined as

```
        [DataMember]
    public bool[] weekDays {get; set;}
```

and I want to have in this array true at positions where days are checked and false where days are not checked

Comment: Looking at your code, you cannot have multiple elements with the same id.  You may think about switching to class based selectors for this.

Comment: can you be more precise, or a few lines of code can be very helpful, thanks

Comment: I just reread this - what does the Html.HiddenFor() generated html code look like?  From there, I think we can get something that works.